# Why do I get "forbids converting a string constant to ‘char*’" in C++?

Tags: c++, char, c-strings, string-literals, function-declaration

I'm trying to invert the case manually, and I tried this:

```
char* invertirCase(char* str){
    int size = 0;
    char* iterador = str;
    char* retorno = str;

    while (*iterador != '\0') {

        if (retorno[size] < 96) {
            retorno[size] = *iterador + 32;
        }
        else {
            retorno[size] = *iterador - 32;
        }
        iterador++;
        size++;
    }

    return retorno;
}
```

I'm trying to figure out where's the error, but I don't get it since I'm pretty new at C++ language.

Comment: Please choose one language. Are you using C or C++?

Comment: Perhaps the error is coming from where you call the function, not from within the function. E.g. if you went `invertirCase("Lol")`

Comment: Isn't it the same since I'm not using OOP? It's C++

Comment: Where in the code do you convert a string constant to `char *`? Do we need to see the code that calls `invertircase`?

Comment: C and C++ handle this somewhat differently. C admits that most of the time doing what you got an error message for is a dumb thing to do, but they let you do it anyway. C++ Stops the build dead and demands you fix it.

Comment: *Isn't it the same since I'm not using OOP?*  No, modern C++ and modern C have diverged a long time ago.  C++ is not, and has never been (as the list of discrepancies continues to grow as each language continues to evolve), a proper superset of C.

Comment: @DiegoGómez C and C++ have a common subset, but they are not the same (and if the commenters are right, your code could've compiled in C, but not in C++). And you can write OOP in C as well, just the language doesn't provide much support for that. OOP is a mindset, not the word `class`.

Comment: This doesn't address the question, but you might want to look at [`std::isupper`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/isupper), [`std::islower`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/islower), [`std::toupper`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/toupper), and [`std::tolower`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/tolower) rather than hand-rolling non-portable versions of these functions.

Comment: Unrelated: Consider replacing the 96 and 32 with the proper characters. It'll make the code a lot easier to process for the folks who haven't memorized the ascii table.  Plus, not everyone uses ascii. And watch out for digits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why do I get "forbids converting a string constant to ‘char*’" in C++?

The error message means that you are trying to pass a string literal to the function.

String literals in C++ have types of constant character arrays that passed by value to functions are implicitly converted to the type `const char *`. And any attempt to change a string literal results in undefined behavior.

You could pass to the function a character array initialized by a string literal as for example

```
char s[] = "Hello";
std::cout << invertirCase( s ) << '\n';
```

In turn the function can be defined the following way

```
#include <cctype>

char * invertirCase( char *str )
{
    for ( char *p = str; *p; ++p )
    {
        unsigned char c = *p;

        if ( std::isalpha( c ) )
        {
            if ( std::islower( c ) )
            {
                *p = std::toupper( c );
            }
            else
            {
                *p = std::tolower( c );
            }
        }
    }

    return str;
}
```

or

```
char * invertirCase( char *str )
{
    for ( char *p = str; *p; ++p )
    {
        unsigned char c = *p;

        if ( std::islower( c ) )
        {
            *p = std::toupper( c );
        }
        else if ( std::isupper( c ) )
        {
            *p = std::tolower( c );
        }
    }

    return str;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no "string constant" in the code you have shown, so it would have to be at the call site, ie if you were doing something like `invertirCase("string")`, which will not work, for 2 reasons:

1. since C++11 onward, C++ does not allow a *string literal* to be assigned to a `char*` pointer.  This is because a string literal is a `const char[]` array, and you can't have a pointer-to-non-const pointing at const data.  So you need to use `const char*` instead.
2. however, that will still not work, because `invertirCase()` modifies the data pointed at by its `str` parameter.  You can't modify the data of a string literal.

So, you will have to make a *copy* of the string literal into writable memory.  You can either make that copy at the call site, eg:

```
char str[] = "string";
invertirCase(str);
```

Or, you can make the copy inside of `invertirCase()` (but then the caller will have to free the copy when done using it), eg:

```
char* invertirCase(const char* str){
    int size = 0;
    char* retorno = new char[strlen(str)+1];

    while (*str != '\0') {
        retorno[size] = (*str < 96) ? (*str + 32) : (*str - 32);
        str++;
        size++;
    }

    retorno[size] = '\0';

    return retorno;
}
```

```
char *str = invertirCase("string");
...
delete[] str;
```

Otherwise, simply don't use `char*` at all.  Use `std::string` instead, eg:

```
std::string invertirCase(const std::string &str){
    std::string retorno;
    retorno.reserve(str.size());
    for(char ch : str) {
        retorno.push_back((ch < 96) ? (ch + 32) : (ch - 32));
    }
    return retorno;
}
```

```
std::string str = invertirCase("string");
...
```